# How to pass alternate color in fill property of label

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I want to apply fill property of 1 dynamic value label as alternate colors , currently using this formula - If(Mod(ThisItem.ProjectIdentifier,2)=0,RGBA(0,0,0,.1),RGBA(127,56,59,47))
But it doesn't seems to work properly ?
This is how it comes now but i need alternate colors .

[image]

Comment: Is this Gallery? If so, are you applying any filters to the Source/Items?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a good general way to do this today.
Upvote this issue: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Ability-to-display-alternate-row-colors-within-a-gallery/idi-p/127518

It's possible if there's a sequential row number (1,2,3,4...) , and then you can use a formula like above with the row number. However, ProjectIdentifier is not the same as the row number.

One hacky way to get sequential row numbers is via Collect() calls as detailed in these links:

https://officepoweruser.com/alternating-row-colors-in-power-apps/
http://powerappsguide.com/blog/post/generating-row-numbers